# Groovy Elvis operator with and logic

Tags: groovy, syntax

This may be a silly question, but I am curious how this operates -

If I have an Elvis operator with an and / or logic in the then clause, how should I write the operation? That sounds confusing, I know, so let me give an example...

```
testVal = test1 ?: test2 && test3
```

Is EVERYTHING on the right side of the Elvis operator considered a separate entity, or is it only what is immediately to the right?

Meaning, does groovy read the code as

```
testVal = (test1 ?: test2) && test 3
```

> If test1 fails, do test2 - let's call this result test12. 
>   testVal = test12 && test3

or does it read it as

```
test1 ?: (test2 && test3)
```

> If test1 fails, do test2 and test 3 - let's call this result test23. 
>   testVal = test1 && test23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_operator_precedence) states that `&&` operator has higher precedence than `?:`.
So the code is executed as `test1 ?: (test2 && test3)`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!